# Как переделать такой запрос?

Tags: php, laravel

Как переделать такой вот запрос в orm
Вот один из таких запросов:

```
DB::table('matches as m')
        ->select('*','t1.image as image_one','t2.image as image_two','m.id as id_bets','t1.id as id_team_1', 't2.id as id_team_2')
        ->join('teams AS t1','t1.name','=','m.name_one')
        ->join('teams AS t2','t2.name','=','m.name_two')
        ->where('m.status','=','1')
        ->get();
```

Вот модель Match:

```
class Match extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'event', 'name_one', 'name_two','balans_one','balans_two','data_event', 'status','win_team','lose_team','koof_one','proc_win_one','koof_two','proc_win_two',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

И вот модель Team:

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'image',
    ];
}
```

И как в Eloquent ORM использовать два "where" в одном запросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Попробуй так:

- В моделях укажи свойства $table с именами таблиц
- Используешь Eloquent запрос с указанием имен моделей, все в примере понятно как работает вложенный запрос через конструкцию "замыкания" (closure)

// Model: Match.php

```
class Match extends Model
{
    public $table = 'matches';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'event', 'name_one', 'name_two','balans_one','balans_two','data_event', 'status','win_team','lose_team','koof_one','proc_win_one','koof_two','proc_win_two',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

// Model: Team.php

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public $table = 'teams';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'image',
    ];
}
```

Сам запрос:

```
Match::select('*')
    ->from((new Match)->getTable() . ' AS m')
    ->leftJoin((new Team)->getTable() . ' AS t1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('t1.name', '=', 'm.name_one');
        $join->on('t1.name', '=', 'm.name_two');
    })
    ->where('m.status','=','1')
    ->get();
```